# Crontab script not generating text file

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, cron

Here is my crontab entry:

`* * * * * /home/ec2-user/Test/test_thing.sh`

Here is the script, `test_thing.sh`:

`echo "asdf" >> ./bla.txt`

When I run it manually, it does generate the "bla.txt" file. However, it does not automatically do so (create the "bla.txt" file within the `/Test/` directory) with the crontab.

I have also checked my `/var/log/cron` file and I see that it is executed every minute, but not sure if it's running into an error or not.

If it is important, I am running this on an Amazon ec2 server, specifically the Amazon Linux AMI.

Edits:
I have also done `chmod +x test_thing.sh` to make sure it is executable.

Comment: The relative path "./blah.txt" might not be where you think it is. Try using an absolute path reference on a folder you know that your user has the permission writing to.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cronjob runs from home directory by default. So you should see the file to be created under /home/ec2-user or /root if you run it by root account.

If you need generate the new file with the nominate path, one way is to use absolute path as @yftse said. The other way is

```
* * * * * cd /home/ec2-user/Test/; bash /home/ec2-user/Test/test_thing.sh
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a quick question (probably out of the scope of this problem so feel free to point me in a direction if necessary). When you `cd` into a directory within the crontab, I'm assuming it doesn't affect other cronjobs, even within the same file? If so, is it a temporary directory change, which then is reverted back to the home directory, or is my assumption wrong?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Your assumption is correct.  You could also choose to put the cd command in the script.